# How to return errors to user after checking input in Go?

Tags: go, web-applications

I am creating a user signup function in Go,
We need a function that receives several fields from the user and displays the error messages returned after validation with playground/v10 to the page that receives data input to the user.

In addition to the error message, I want to send along with the data entered by the user, including data that has passed validation and is fine.

As far as validation, there are many examples on the Internet, but I can't find an example that transmits both the error data and the data entered by the user to the previous page.

```
// Register Page
func RegisterPage(c echo.Context) error {
    template.Renders(c, "app/view/manager/page/register.html", "app/view/manager/layout/defaultLayout.html")
    err := c.Render(200, "register.html", "")

    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(400, err.Error())
    }
    return nil
}

// Register logic
func Register(c echo.Context) error {
    var inData req.ManagerRegister
    
    errData := binder.Bind(c, &inData)
    if errData != nil {
        return RegisterPage(c)
    }
    return c.Redirect(301, "/main")
}
```

1. In registerPage, user enters data. / - success -
2. User data is verified in registerLogic, / - success -
3. Redirect unpassed data and error messages to registerPage / - I need help with this part -

What function or something is needed in the example code above?

Comment: you need ajax(js)....